# Splash screen while an exe file is opening

Tags: python, batch-file, pyqt, splash-screen, py2exe

This might be a common issue but I couldn't find a good solution. I have compiled a python program with an interface made with pyqt4 using py2exe. It is a bit big (150mb) but it is running fast enough in my computer. The goal is to run it in a remote computer (in a sharedfolder) but it takes around 15 seconds to open. I prepared a splash screen with a pyqt library but then it takes 15 seconds to come for the splash screen :).

Anyway, so I need to make it work in another way and I don't know how. It will be used by my colleques and they will be frustrated after clicking the file if they don't know they have to wait 15 seconds for a program to start.

Can I just create a standalone splash image or something that will trigger my exe in the same time and it will be shown during this waiting time?

Comment: I think the issue (simular to pyinstaller) is the unpacking time of the entire package. My colleque solved this by writing 2 programms: One for the spalshscreen which starts the unpacking of the second one (which is the big one). Second one then starts and is detected by user32.dll `EnumWIndows`

Comment: How is this related to tag [tag:batch-file]?

Comment: I added the tag because I was thinking to create a batch file to run my program and a splash screen in the same time. But it might not work in this way.